# Why does Google think that Midori is Chrome?

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, chromium, google, midori

This is on Lubuntu 16.04 (running XFCE.)

I don't really care, I'm just curious. Is Midori built on Chromium or something?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Midori uses the WebKit rendering engine, and has a User-Agent which resembles an older Chrome User-Agent header. This is why Google is showing the update suggestion.